# How can a Popup like the "Select Wi-Fi Network" alert be implemented

Tags: ios, user-interface, popup, overlay, uialertview

In iOS, a popup is shown from time to time that asks the user to join a Wi-Fi network.

[image: Select a Wi-Fi Network]

I want to implement a similar popup with custom contents

- Title
- TableView with a varying amount of entries (if too many, with scrollbar)
- Cancel button
- Popup over an existing view (the popup is smaller than the view)
- How can such an effect be achieved? I guess that UIAlertView may be a good starting point. However, UIAlertView does not support subclassing

  > The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with the system UIAlertView. You have to code your own, or use an open source component.

This could be a starting point/example: [BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets](https://github.com/gpambrozio/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets)

Comment: I do not want to add more dependencies to the code. How to do it manually from scratch? (I want to understand how it works without libraries).

Comment: Than look at that library. Its open source, you can see all the code.

Comment: The best way to learn in some cases is to retype the code linked above in your own project. That way you will learn while efficiently achieving your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, it is exactly the thing you need: [github example project](https://github.com/blommegard/SBTableAlert)